# Serverless: Fire and forget by invoke method does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-edge

I have a **Serverless** **lambda** function, in which I want to fire(invoke) a method and forget about it

I'm doing it with this way

```
   // myFunction1
   const params = {
    FunctionName: "myLambdaPath-myFunction2", 
    InvocationType: "Event", 
    Payload: JSON.stringify(body), 
   };

   console.log('invoking lambda function2'); // Able to log this line
   lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });


  // my function2 handler
  myFunction2 = (event) => {
   console.log('does not come here') // Not able to log this line
  }
```

I've noticed that until and unless I do a `Promise` `return` in `myFunction1`, it does not trigger `myFunction2`, but shouldn't set the lambda `InvocationType = "Event"` mean we want this to be **fire and forget** and not care about the callback response?

Am I missing something here?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the logs in Cloudwatch as to why the invocation is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myFunction1` should be an async function that's why the function returns before `myFunction2` could be invoked in `lambda.invoke()`. Change the code to the following then it should work:

```
 const params = {
    FunctionName: "myLambdaPath-myFunction2", 
    InvocationType: "Event", 
    Payload: JSON.stringify(body), 
 };

 console.log('invoking lambda function2'); // Able to log this line
 return await lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err, err.stack);
     } else {
       console.log(data);
     }
 }).promise();


 // my function2 handler
 myFunction2 = async (event) => {
   console.log('does not come here') // Not able to log this line
 }
```

Comment: you don't need the callback if you're using .promise?